# Comparing speeds of different tasks in different languages

Tags: language-agnostic

If I wanted to test out the speeds it takes for certain tasks to be done, would it matter what language I did the test in? We can consider this to be any job a programmer might want to perform. Simple jobs such as sorting, or more complicated jobs which involve the signing and verification of files.

Considering that we all know that certain languages will run faster than others, this means that the tasks will rely upon the languages and the way their compilers / runtimes are optimised. But these will obviously all be different.

So is it best to rely upon a language which relies less on abstraction such as C, or is it OK to test out jobs and tasks in more high level languages, and rely on the fact that they are implemented well enough not to worry about any possible inefficiencies? I hope my question is clear.

Comment: I think it's pretty safe to say that the higher-level a language is, the more overhead it will have, and therefore the slower it will execute.  So, Assembly will run almost instantly compared to VB (for instance).

Comment: Forgive me, thats not what I meant by the question. I mean that is a comparison between different ways of doing jobs (ie lets call it sorting method 1 v sorting method 2) in any language likely to give similar results in all languages, or is it likely that differences in languages (i'm not including other types of languages such as functional languages) can make differences to these kinds of tests?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to compare.  If you want to compare the speeds of different tasks (algorithms), use the same language for all the tasks.  If you want to compare the speeds of different languages (implementations), use the same task.  If you try to compare different tasks in different languages, you have too many variables and can't really conclude anything.

Comment: OK. Would I consider something such as hashing, or signing, to be an algorithm, since they are made up of steps similar to algorithms? Then I would rely on the fact that whoever implemented said algorithm did it in the best way possible?

Comment: @user3465120:  If you want to get a benchmark for how different languages handle the same thing, then you could run a test that could be done across a bunch of different languages.  Say, write a routine to calculate the first 2000 prime numbers.  Decide on the most efficient method, and run it in Javascript, PHP, C#, etc.  See which one runs the fastest.  Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it doesn't matter which real-world language you use for your tests... if you design the tests correctly. there is always an overhead of the language but there is always an overhead of the operating system, thread scheduler, IO, ram or speed of electricity that depends on current temperature etc.

but to compare anything you don't want to measure how many nanoseconds it took to do the one assignment statement. instead you want to measure how many hours it took to do billions of assignment statements. then all mentioned overheads are negligible